# Is it possible to use Select Same commands on a particular artboard in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections

I want to select objects on a particular artboard using **Select —> Same** command (Stroke Weight in my case).

How can I do that?

Adobe Illustrator CC 2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, it's not possible to limit `Select > Same` to a specific artboard.

However, you can lock everything else first.

There is a somewhat hidden shortcut....

- Select all objects on the artboard you *want* to use
- Hold the <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> keys and hit the <kbd>2</kbd>. 
  This command will "lock others", i.e. anything *not* selected.
  Basically, it's the standard lock shortcut with <kbd>Shift</kbd> added.
- Use the `Select > Same` and it will not select the (other) locked objects.
- When done, merely unlock in the traditional manner - 
  <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> e.g. `Object > Unlock All`.

If you have a layer structure, it's also possible to merely lock the layers you do *not* want the select command to use.

Note, adding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the `Hide` shortcut works the same way for "Hide Others".

Comment: Thanks, with the hidden lock shortcut the workaround is pretty quick and usable.